# Connecting two DStreams to have separate mapWithState States

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We are using mapWithState to keep track of incoming Booking events.  Once a group of Booking events has been completed I would like to publish a new Order event to a different Spark Stream, which will have its own key and its own state.  Bookings will be on the Account level, and Orders will be on the Client level.  I can create two custom streams like this:

```
val bookingsReceiver = new MyJMSReceiver()
val bookingsReceiverStream = ssc.receiverStream(bookingsReceiver)
val ordersReceiver = new MyCustomInMemoryReceiver()
val ordersReceiverStream = ssc.receiverStream(ordersReceiver)
```

So the definitions of the mapWithState State Specs would look like this

```
def bookingsStateFunc(batchTime: Time, key: AccountID, value: Option[Booking], state: State[(AccountID, BookingRequest)]): Option[(AccountID, BookingRequest)]

def ordersStateFunc(batchTime: Time, key: ClientID, value: Option[Order], state: State[(ClientID, OrderHistory)]): Option[(ClientID, OrderHistory)]
```

And I can create a new Order when a Booking is complete, like this:

```
ordersStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.filter(_._2.bookingStatus == BookingStatus.Completed).foreach { bookingRequest =>
    val order = Order(bookingRequest)
    // What can I do to send the new Order to the Orders stream?
    ordersReceiver.storeOrder(order) //This will not work as ordersReceiver is not available on the Workers ...
  }
}
```

I could create an external message queue to publish the new Orders to.  But is there a way to either chain the new data to an existing stream?  Or is there a way to collect the new data to the Driver?

This example Custom Receiver will not work but shows how I am thinking...

```
class MyCustomInMemoryReceiver extends Receiver[Order](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2) {
  def onStart() = {}
  def onStop() = {}
  def storeOrder(order: Order) = store(order)
}
```

Comment: I use Kafka. Spark lets you listen to multiple topics within one Kafka DStream. Maybe you could take the same approach, and merge the streams in `MyCustomReceiver()` ?

Comment: I don't have Kafka so I was hoping there would be another way of doing this...

Comment: Understood no Kafka. Point was, do what the Kafka Spark integration does -- merge the streams in your receiver so your DStream has both

Comment: Merging streams isn't the problem though.  The issue is that the events for the second stream get created in the first stream's foreachRDD.  How to get the new events from the foreachRDD into the second Receiver so that they can be stored (by calling store(event))?  Using Kafka is a good solution but I would like to see if there is a way without adding an external dependency.  I hope this is a bit more clear, and thanks for responding.

Comment: No worries. I think you are still misunderstanding me. Can you post the code for `MyCustomReceiver` ?

Comment: Hi David, I have updated the question to show that the first Receiver is getting data from an external source and that the second one will be internal.  Hope this clarifies things.  I know the code shown won't work, but that is the kind of thing I am hoping might be possible.

Comment: @Patrick What happens with the `Order` object? Should it only be available in memory for Spark or do external resources need to access it as well?

Comment: Hi Yuval, the Order objects will only be used by Spark, no need for external resources to access it.  The question is, is it possible to push data generated in one Spark Stream to another, without using an external staging component (e.g. Kafka).  I'm starting to think its not possible.